# 2d rotation on set of points causes skewing distortion

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, 2d

I'm writing an application in OpenGL (though I don't think this problem is related to that). I have some 2d point set data that I need to rotate. It later gets projected into 3d.

I apply my rotation using this formula:

```
x' = x cos f - y sin f
y' = y cos f + x sin f
```

Where 'f' is the angle. When I rotate the point set, the result is skewed. The severity of the effect varies with the angle.

It's hard to describe so I have pictures;
The red things are some simple geometry. The 2d point sets are the vertices for the white polylines you see around them. The first picture shows the undistorted pointsets, and the second picture shows them after rotation. It's not just skew that's occuring with the rotation; sometimes it seems like displacement occurs as well.

[image]

[image]

The code itself is trivial:

```
double cosTheta = cos(2.4);
double sinTheta = sin(2.4);
CalcSimplePolyCentroid(listHullVx,xlate);
for(size_t j=0; j < listHullVx.size(); j++)   {

    // translate
    listHullVx[j] = listHullVx[j] - xlate;

    // rotate
    double xPrev = listHullVx[j].x;
    double yPrev = listHullVx[j].y;
    listHullVx[j].x = ((xPrev*cosTheta) - (yPrev*sinTheta));
    listHullVx[j].y = ((yPrev*cosTheta) + (xPrev*sinTheta));

    // translate
    listHullVx[j] = listHullVx[j] + xlate;
}
```

If I comment out the code under '//rotate' above, the output of the application is the first image. And adding it back in gives the second image. There's literally nothing else that's going on (afaik).

The data types being used are all doubles so I don't think its a precision issue. Does anyone have any idea why rotation would cause skewing like the above pictures show?

EDIT
filipe's comment below was correct. This probably has nothing to do with the rotation and I hadn't provided enough information for the problem;

The geometry I've shown in the pictures represents buildings. They're generated from lon/lat map coordinates. In the point data I use to do the transform, I forgot to use an actual projection to cartesian coordinate space and just mapped x->lon, y->lat, and I think this is the reason I'm seeing the distortion. I'm going to request that this question be deleted since I don't think it'll be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Your formula is effectively a 2D rotation matrix. I suggest you learn how to use transformation matrices, as those make composing transformation really easy.

Comment: just a thought, the skewing could also be happening when rendering, and not when transforming the data itself. Have you tried setting the data to some hardcoded value to see if it renders as you expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
As a result of your comments it tunred out the it is unlikely that the bug is in the presented code.

One final other hint: std transform formulars are only valid if the cooridnate system is cartesian, 
on ios you sometimes have inverted y Achsis.

Comment: 'listHullVx' just stands for "list of hull vertices". "xlate" just stands for 'translate'. Sorry if it was confusing in my code, but when I translate, I subtract a "Vec2" object from another "Vec2"... this does both the x and y translations.

Comment: are your rotation  angles in radians?

Comment: Yep. Even if they were specified in degrees by accident, sin() and cos() wouldn't care; I'd still get a proper rotation (at the wrong angle). I think I may have been premature in posting this question, and that the problem lies elsewhere... I'll update or close this question accordingly shortly.

Comment: Yes the rotation is correct, it must be elsewhere, or the translation would not work.